# 100+ dates in different timezones, calculate which 2 dates present day is between...more calculate

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am really having a heck of a time figuring out which way I should do this. Been coding objective-c for 4 months now, well trying to at least.

I have about 100+ different dates spanning 2012, down to the second, in multiple timezones. What I need is:

- to grab the present time/date, see which 2 dates in my 100+ list it is between and give me time spent and time remaining.
- to know which 2 dates it is between no matter what timezone a user is in.
- all calculations need to take in consideration of daylight savings time. Which the dates and times of DST change is different depending on the timezone and country.
- a user in Hawaii will have the same time remaining and spent as a user in England.
- ablility to convert all times to local user time.
- have this all realtime. have the clock or timer counting down to the second.

I have tried NSDate. Then I searched this site and found NSDateFormatter. I played with that for what seems like days. Then another search I found NSDateComponents. Do I put my 100+ dates in a multidimensional  array. Do I convert everything to GMT first or can xcode do that for me. Or do I convert everytime to seconds since 1970. I am just lost on what would be the best most practical way of doing this.

Any help, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an iOS programmer, but if you could convert everything to the same time zone (MST, EST, GMT, whatever), then that would make your job far easier. Converting between time zones runs in constant time as there is nothing more involved than simple addition/subtraction.

As for DST, if you convert to MST or EST (as opposed to MDT or EDT), you inherently remove DST. What exactly do you mean by "take in consideration of DST?" I could help much more if you could provide that.

Comment: New York DST is:
Starts: Sunday, March 11 at 2:00 AM
Ends: Sunday, November 4 at 2:00 AM

London DST is:
Starts: Sunday, March 25 at 1:00 AM
Ends: Sunday, October 28 at 2:00 AM

If one date is New York and the other is London, by converting them to GMT am I loosing the dates when DST starts and stops in the country?

EX: If one date is March 10 at 3:00pm EST and the other is
                   March 28 at 5:00pm BST, EDT is still daylight but EST is not. depending on where the user is located, will the time spent and time remaining be the same for a user in NY and a user in the UK?